# Radon-Nikodym of Transition Kernel of Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

Let $M_n$ be a Markov chain on $\mathcal{X}$ with transition kernel $P$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{Pr}(M_{n+1}\in A|M_0=x) = \int_A P(x,dy).
\end{equation}
For each $x$ in  $\mathcal{X}$  kernel $P(x,dy)$ is also a measure on $\mathcal{X}$ in the following sense: for a subset $A$ of $\mathcal{X}$
    \begin{equation}
    P(x, A) := \int_{A} P(x, dy).
\end{equation}

Suppose $\pi$ is a stationary measure for the chain, i.e. $\pi P=\pi$. My question is: as a measure, is $P(x,dy)$ absolutely continuous with respect to $\pi$?

If $\pi(A)=0$, then because $\pi$ is stationary this implies $[\pi P](A)=0$. From here, 
\begin{align*}
[\pi P](A) & = \int P(x, A) \pi(dx).
\end{align*}
Knowing $P(x, A)$ is nonnegative for each $x$ implies $P(x, A)=0$ for all $x$, and this shows $P(x,\cdot)<< \pi(\cdot)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe I forgot definitions, but didn't you show $P(x,.) \ll \pi(.)$?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to show. I noticed I switched the order in the last line. Fixed it thanks!

Comment: Looks right. Though "from here" seems like the wrong transition word, since what follows it is always true. You should say "Since ... and since $P(x,A)$ is non-negative for each $x$, we obtain $P(x,A) = 0$ for all $x$, and ..."